# Plot ROC curve and calculate AUC in R at specific cutoff info

Tags: r, curve, roc, auc

Given such data:
SN = Sensitivity;
SP = Specificity

```
Cutpoint        SN   1-SP
       1       0.5    0.1
       2       0.7    0.2
       3       0.9    0.6
```

How can i plot the ROC curve and calculate AUC. And compare the AUC between two different ROC curves. In the most of the packages such pROC or ROCR, the input of the data is different from those shown above. Can anybody suggest the way to solve this problem in R or by something else?

```
ROCsdat <- data.frame(cutpoint = c(5, 7, 9), TPR = c(0.56, 0.78, 0.91), FPR = c(0.01, 0.19, 0.58))

## plot version 1
op <- par(xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i")
plot(TPR ~ FPR, data = dat, xlim = c(0,1), ylim = c(0,1), type = "n")
with(dat, lines(c(0, FPR, 1), c(0, TPR, 1), type = "o", pch = 25, bg = "black"))
text(TPR ~ FPR, data = dat, pos = 3, labels = dat$cutpoint)
abline(0, 1)
par(op)
```

Comment: Do you only have those three points? If your data is different than what those functions take, then manipulate your data. For calculating AUC, you can use `Hmisc::somers2`. And comparing AUCs between ROC curves is not advisable.

Comment: For an example i have given only three points but i have atleast six cutoff points at which there is Sensitivity and Specificity at each individual cutoff.

Comment: well, ROC curves have `1 - specificity` on the x-axis and `sensitivity` on the y-axis. Did you try plotting that?

Comment: I have no problems in plotting them but was not able to calculate the AUC?

Comment: Is the data loaded (for instance in a data frame) or do you have it in a file?

Comment: I have used this code which was available for                         ROCsdat <- data.frame(cutpoint = c(5, 7, 9),
                  TPR = c(0.56, 0.78, 0.91),
                  FPR = c(0.01, 0.19, 0.58))

## plot version 1    
op <- par(xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i")
plot(TPR ~ FPR, data = dat, xlim = c(0,1), ylim = c(0,1), type = "n")
with(dat, lines(c(0, FPR, 1), c(0, TPR, 1), type = "o", pch = 25, bg = "black"))
text(TPR ~ FPR, data = dat, pos = 3, labels = dat$cutpoint)
abline(0, 1)
par(op)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, I would recommend to visit your local library and find an introductory book on R. It is important to have a solid base before you can write your own code, and copy-pasting code found on the internet without really understanding what is means is risky at best.

Regarding your question, I believe the (0,0) and (1,1) cooordinates are part of the ROC curve so I included them in the data:

```
ROCsdat <- data.frame(cutpoint = c(-Inf, 5, 7, 9, Inf), TPR = c(0, 0.56, 0.78, 0.91, 1), FPR = c(0, 0.01, 0.19, 0.58, 1))
```

## AUC

I strongly recommend against setting up your own trapezoid integration function at this stage of your training in R. It's too error-prone and easy to screw up with a small (syntax) mistake.

Instead, use a well established integration code like the `trapz` function in `pracma`:

```
library(pracma)
trapz(ROCsdat$FPR, ROCsdat$TPR)
```

## Plotting

I think you mostly got the plotting, although I would write it slightly differently:

```
plot(TPR ~ FPR, data = ROCsdat, xlim = c(0,1), ylim = c(0,1), type="b", pch = 25, bg = "black")
text(TPR ~ FPR, data = ROCsdat, pos = 3, labels = ROCsdat$cutpoint)
abline(0, 1, col="lightgrey")
```

## Comparison

For the comparison, let's say you have two AUCs in `auc1` and `auc2`. The if/else syntax looks like this:

```
if (auc1 < auc2) {
    cat("auc1 < auc2!\n")
} else if (auc1 == auc2) {
    cat("aucs are identical!\n")
} else {
    cat("auc1 > auc2!\n")
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help and code. In the comparison of AUCs, i have seen people giving a non-parametric comparisons as suggested in this following link http://circ.ahajournals.org/content/115/5/654.full. Can you help me on this??

Comment: @RamT <you can't apply those methods with your data - in fact you can't apply any statistical test when you don't even know the sample size.

Comment: @RamT I believe you generated the sn/sp from some data. Use that data as input to one of the packages you mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you could just compute it manually:

```
dat <- data.frame(tpr=c(0, .5, .7, .9, 1), fpr=c(0, .1, .2, .6, 1))
sum(diff(dat$fpr) * (dat$tpr[-1] + dat$tpr[-length(dat$tpr)]) / 2)
# [1] 0.785
```

You need to have the `tpr` and `fpr` vectors begin with 0 and end with 1 to compute the AUC properly.

Comment: Can you explain me the formula of this AUC in detail? And also how do we compare AUC of two ROC curves to give p-value. Thnq!!

Comment: I'm computing the areas of the segments of the ROC curve (each segment is a trapezoid).

Comment: Ya i understood!!..Can you also help me on this comparison part?? Comparison of AUC of two ROC curves?