# How to obtain auc, specificity and sensitivity for a given cutoff value in R?

Tags: r, roc, auc

Suppose I have the data below

```
set.seed(4)
ctt <- runif(50,0,10)
status <- rbinom(50,1,0.7) # 0 control, 1 patient
```

and subjects with `ctt >4.5` are `normal (false positive)` and `ctt < 4.5` are `abnormal (false negative)`. In this case, how could I obtain the ROC curve and `auc, specifitiy` and `sensitivity`?

Comment: are you asking if there's a specific function in R to calculate those, or what the equations would be to calculate?

Comment: How I do it does not matter. I am interested in the results. So, both are fine with me

Comment: Well, one is kind of vaguely related to a programming question you might see on this site, and the other is blatantly off-topic.

Comment: I thought you meant to use some equations in R to get what I want by the second option. However, the first option sounded shorter. Therefore, I said both are fine as long as they give the same result.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22413349/plot-roc-curve-and-calculate-auc-in-r-at-specific-cutoff-info?rq=1